# Changing middle line to some other symbol. Latex Table

Tags: tables, math-mode

```
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $ \langle R_1.Y \rangle$ & $ \langle \dot{-}R_2.X, \dot{-}R_2.X \rangle$\\
   \hline
  $\langle a \rangle$  &   \\
    \hline
   \hline
   $\langle b \rangle$ &  \\
    \hline
    &  $\langle c,c \rangle$ \\
   \hline 
  \end{tabular}
```

Hi,
             I am trying to create a table in that only middle line for some rows, should be changed to disjunction symbol. (`\vee`). Alignment should be proper. Multi-column is not working properly.

Comment: Please provide a full working MWE.  Also, you have a lot of white space in your example which will create other effects.  In particular, blank lines are treated as paragraph breaks.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: How does the `\dot{-}` operator work?

Comment: It's a notation from a research paper. Toggle the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $ \langle R_1.Y \rangle$ & $ \langle \dot{-}R_2.X, \dot{-}R_2.X \rangle$\\
   \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|r}{ $\langle a \rangle$} &  \multicolumn{1}{!{\clap{$\vee$}}c|}{$\langle b,b \rangle $} \\
  \hline
   \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{   $\langle a \rangle $}   \\
    \hline
    &  $\langle c,c \rangle$ \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`mathtools` needed for `\clap` and `array` needed for `!` in `!{\clap{$\vee$}`

Since this involves only math content, it is better to use `array` instead of `tabular` thereby saving all those `$`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}
\begin{document}
  $\begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline
   \langle R_1.Y \rangle &  \langle \dot{-}R_2.X, \dot{-}R_2.X \rangle\\
   \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|r}{ \langle a \rangle} &  \multicolumn{1}{!{\mathclap{\vee}}c|}{\langle b,b \rangle } \\
  \hline
   \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{   \langle a \rangle }   \\
    \hline
    &  \langle c,c \rangle \\
   \hline
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius :) Yes Perfectly